# How to embade osTicket with php?

Tags: php, osticket

I want to embade osticket with my php project, i downloaded and try to run on localhost  but it through **Fatal Error by: Contact system administrator.**

Answer (score 0):

Please chceck ost-config.php file you might have entered some wrong database details.